# Is it possible to use transactions in Spring AOP advice?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-aop

I am trying to implement logging in DB table using Spring AOP. By "logging in table" I mean to write in special log table information about record that was CREATED/UPDATED/DELETED in usual table for domain object.

I wrote some part of the code and all is working good except one thing - when transaction is rolled back then changes in log table still commit successfully. It's strange for me because in my AOP advice the same transaction is using as in my business and DAO layer. (From my AOP advice I called methods of special manager class with Transaction propagation MANDATORY and also I checked transaction name *TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName()* in business layer, dao layer and AOP advice and it is the same).

Does anyone tried to implement similar things in practice? Is it possible to use in AOP advice the same transaction as in the business layer and rollback changes made in AOP advice if some error in business layer occurs?

Thank you in advance for unswers.

**EDIT**

I want to clarify that problem with rollback occurs only for changes that was made from AOP advice. All changes that is made in DAO layer are rollbacked successfully. I mean that, for example, if some exception is thrown then changes made in DAO layer will be successfully rollbacked, but in log table information will be saved (commited). But I can't understand why it is like that because as I wrote above in AOP advice the same transaction is using.

**EDIT 2**

I checked with debugger the piece of the code where I am writting to the log table in AOP advice and it seems to me that JdbcTemplate's update method executes outside transaction because changes had been commited to the DB directly after execution of the statement and before transactional method was finished.

**EDIT 3**

I solved this problem. Actually, that was my stupid fault. I'm using MySQL. After creation of the log table I did't change DB engine and HeidySQL set MyIsam by default. But MyIsam doesn't support transaction so I changed DB engine to InnoDB (as for all other tables) and now all is working perfectly.

Thank you all for help and sorry for disturbing.

If someone is interested, here is simplified example that illustrate my approach.

Consider DAO class that has save method:

```
@Repository(value="jdbcUserDAO")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly=true, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public class JdbcUserDAO implements UserDAO {
@Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @LoggedOperation(affectedRows = AffectedRows.ONE, loggedEntityClass = User.class, operationName = OperationName.CREATE)
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    @Override
    public User save(final User user) {
        if (user == null || user.getRole() == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input User object or nested Role object should not be null");
        }

        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                    throws SQLException {

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT_USER, new String[]{"ID"});

                ps.setString(1, user.getUsername());
                ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
                ps.setString(3, user.getFullName());
                ps.setLong(4, user.getRole().getId());
                ps.setString(5, user.geteMail());

                return ps;
            }
        }, keyHolder);

        user.setId((Long) keyHolder.getKey());

        VacationDays vacationDays = user.getVacationDays();
        vacationDays.setId(user.getId());

        // Create related vacation days record.
        vacationDaysDAO.save(vacationDays);

        user.setVacationDays(vacationDays);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Here is how aspect looks like:

```
@Component
@Aspect
@Order(2)
public class DBLoggingAspect {

    @Autowired
    private DBLogManager dbLogManager;

    @Around(value = "execution(* com.crediteuropebank.vacationsmanager.server.dao..*.*(..)) " +
            "&& @annotation(loggedOperation)",  argNames="loggedOperation")
    public Object doOperation(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
            final LoggedOperation loggedOperation) throws Throwable {

        Object[] arguments = joinPoint.getArgs();

        /*
         * This should be called before logging operation.
         */
        Object retVal = joinPoint.proceed();

        // Execute logging action
        dbLogManager.logOperation(arguments, 
                loggedOperation);

        return retVal;
    }

}
```

And here is how my db log manager class LooksLike:

```
@Component("dbLogManager")
public class DBLogManager { 

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @InjectLogger
    private Logger logger;

    @Transactional(rollbackFor={Exception.class}, propagation=Propagation.MANDATORY, readOnly=false)
    public void logOperation(final Object[] inputArguments, final LoggedOperation loggedOperation) {


        try {

             /*
              * Prepare query and array of the arguments
              */

            jdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery.toString(), 
                    insertedValues);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            // Prepare log string

            logger.error(sb.toString(), e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you included a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example that demonstrates you're transaction issue.

Comment: Ok. I will add an example but a little later because I have urgent task. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It could be to do with the order of the advice - you would want your @Transaction related advice to take effect around(or before and after) your logging related advice. If you are using Spring AOP you can probably control it using the order attribute of the advice - give your transaction related advice the highest precedence so that it executes last on the way out.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about this and tried to change order of the advices. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with AOP, set datasource property `autocommit` to false like :

```
<bean id="datasource" ...>
    <property name="autoCommit" value="false/>
</bean>
```

If you are using xml configuration

Comment: May be I understand you wrong, but it seems to me that setting autocommit to true will not help me. I need to commit changes (made in AOP advice too) only when tarnsaction is successfully finished. But if I will set autoCommit to true then each statement will be commited automatically automatically after execution. And this will brake business logic (in my case I need to commit changes in DB only after few operation during one transaction have been successfully finished).

Comment: @dimas : yeah I was wrong actually you need to set it to false. As by default it is true. Edited the answer.

Comment: I'm using c3p0 DataSource and there setAutoCommitOnClose proberty is false by default. (But in dbcp BasicDataSource default auto commit value is true, you are right.) And by the way, in my case rollback action is working correct for code that is run from business and DAO layers, the problem occurs only with code that is run from AOP advice.